# Feature Request: Providing Notification for favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, favorites-notifications

Would it be possible to add notification for favorite questions.

Currently, I have to check back from to time for updates. Surely if I add something as favorite, I would want to receive notification about it.

Comment: On your user profile, do you have "I don't want notifications of activity on questions I've favorited" checked?

Comment: Where is the located, I can't seem to find it?

Comment: Hey, found it.. it is not checked. I am wondering why I don't get notifications then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is already in:

Just check the **favorites** tab of your /recent (envelope) page

[image]

However there is a small, new bug where it won't show you new answers on favorites. We'll fix that ASAP.

Comment: has this feature been removed again? I don't see a "notification option" on my favorites tab